# Delegate problem with NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, delegates

I am just starting with OSX development, and I am trying to get delegate notifications from a NSTextField. I've got the following code so far:

This is where I set the delegate:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    NSLog(@"Setting delegate");
    [amountField setDelegate: [[TextfieldController alloc] initWithLog]];
}
```

And this is my TextfieldController:

```
- (TextfieldController *) initWithLog {
    self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"TextfieldController initialized");
    return self;
}

- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"textdidChange");
}


- (void)keyUp:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"keyUp");
}
```

However, neither textDidChange nor keyUp is ever called... Not sure what I'm missing here, because the same way works just fine when I use it for my main window with the windowDidMiniaturize notification...

Anyone able to help? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The delegate should implement `-controlTextDidChange:`, not `-textDidChange:`. The `-textDidChange:` method is a method *on NSTextField* which causes it to post a notification and call `[self.delegate controlTextDidChange:]`. As for `-keyUp:`, that's part of `NSControl`'s event-handling behaviour. If you want your delegate to receive a message when the textfield handles a key up event, you'll need to arrange that yourself by subclassing `NSTextField`.